# Adblock Plus for Chrome blocking links in H3 but not H2 - Any way around that?

Tags: adblock

I have a site where Adblock Plus for Chrome is blocking links in H3 but not H2 elements.  It seems strange I could just change them to H2 and it would work.  But I have a lot of sites that have this potential issue.  Is there a way way around that issue?

Why would H3 be an ad threat but not H2?

Here is some test code of this in action:

```
<div id="topCenterBlock">
    <h3><a href="stackoverflow.com/sign_me_in.jsp?article=" target="_blank" name="top story">A test headline</a> </h3>
    <div class="source"><a href="stackoverflow.com/index.jsp" target="_blank" name="top story:source">Stack Overflow</a></div>
    <br>
    <div class="source"> 2:30 P.M. ET </div>
    <p>Test view of a extract from the article that would display under a link</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it may be the class it is named, `class="ad_container"`. Can you link your website or post some example code of this in-action? I have adblock and I'd like to test this out.

Comment: Thanks.  Each of the blocks are in a container in this format -- altered for format, obv it's not really for stackoverflow.com

Comment: <div id="topCenterBlock">
<h3><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/sign_me_in.jsp?article=http://www.stackoverflow.com/article.jsp?id=1234567890" target="_blank" name="&amp;lpos=top story">A test headline</a>
</h3>
<div class="source"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/index.jsp" target="_blank" name="&amp;lpos=top story:source">Stack Overflow</a></div>
<br><div class="source"> 2:30 P.M. ET </div>
<p>Test view of a extract from the article that would display under a link</p>
</div>

Comment: In other words, no unusual class. I would have thought it was the browser spawn that was the trigger, but simply changing to h2 seemed to "fix" it. Seems like an invalid threat for a trigger. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce this behavior in Chrome 28, 30 and Firefox 22. Can you upload a snapshot of your filterlists within AdBlock settings? Please look a look at your manual filters as well.

Answer (score 1):

They would only be the default from install. I only installed the product so I could see the behavior, which one of our users complained about. I can get a snap later to show but it's just the set out of the box.

Comment: Actually, would it help?  It's 2418 lines of default filters.  I haven't added any of my own.